# Powershell and working with XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to work on writing a powershell script that parses a XMl that is generated by our application. The problem that I'm running into is I'm not able to group the data accordingly and I'm sure it's something that I'm not doing properly.

Here is a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<CustomerInfo name="Widget_Works" areaid="Enterprise" categoryid="Automotive">
<Customer name="Customer Contact">
<Customer name="Name" value="John Doe"/>
<Customer name="Location" value="Texas"/>
</Customer>
<Customer name="Customer Orders">
<Customer name="OrderItem_0" value="3|7|Car Widgets"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_1" value="3|7|Engine Widget"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_2" value="3|7|Chasis Widget"/>
</Customer>
</CustomerInfo>
<CustomerInfo name="Widget_Inc" areaid="Enterprise" categoryid="Automotive">
<Customer name="Customer Contact">
<Customer name="Name" value="Jane Doe"/>
<Customer name="Location" value="New York"/>
</Customer>
<Customer name="Customer Orders">
<Customer name="OrderItem_0" value="1|4|Car Widgets"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_1" value="3|7|Engine Widget"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_2" value="1|4|Chasis Widget"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_3" value="1|4|Windshield Widget"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_4" value="1|4|Tire Widget"/>
</Customer>
</CustomerInfo>
<CustomerInfo name="Widget_Inc" areaid="Enterprise" categoryid="Train">
<Customer name="Customer Contact">
<Customer name="Name" value="Jane Doe"/>
<Customer name="Location" value="New York"/>
</Customer>
<Customer name="Customer Orders">
<Customer name="OrderItem_0" value="1|4|Train Car Widgets"/>
<Customer name="OrderItem_1" value="3|7|Engine Widget"/>
</Customer>
</CustomerInfo>
</root>
```

The part I'm struggling with is I want to only show anything that is Automotive with all the orders along with the CustomerInfo name beside the orders.

This only gets the names but, not sure how to filter by teh categoryID

```
 $xml.root.customerinfo | select name

 name
 ----
Widget_Works
Widget_Inc
Widget_Inc
```

Then getting only the orders outputted and matched to the Customer name is where I'm not sure the right syntax as well as how to break into extra columns when it sees the "|" in teh value string for the order.

```
$xml.root.customerinfo.customer.customer

name                                                        value
----                                                        -----
Name                                                        John Doe
Location                                                    Texas
OrderItem_0                                                 3|7|Car Widgets
OrderItem_1                                                 3|7|Engine Widget
OrderItem_2                                                 3|7|Chasis Widget
Name                                                        Jane Doe
Location                                                    New York
OrderItem_0                                                 1|4|Car Widgets
OrderItem_1                                                 3|7|Engine Widget
OrderItem_2                                                 1|4|Chasis Widget
OrderItem_3                                                 1|4|Windshield Widget
OrderItem_4                                                 1|4|Tire Widget
Name                                                        Jane Doe
Location                                                    New York
OrderItem_0                                                 1|4|Train Car Widgets
OrderItem_1                                                 3|7|Engine Widget
```

Basically only wanting an output like this:

```
Order             Status        Status2             Customer Name
Car Widgets          3              7                 Widget Works
Engine Widgets       3              7                 Widget Works
Chasis Widgets       3              7                 Widget Works
Car Widgets          1              4                 Widget Inc
Engine Widgets       3              7                 Widget Inc
Chasis Widgets       1              4                 Widget Inc
Windshield Widgets   1              4                 Widget Inc
Tire Widgets         1              4                 Widget Inc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an xpath query to filter out by category id, then you can expand the nodes to get the info:

```
$automotiveCustomers = select-xml '/root/CustomerInfo[@categoryid="Automotive"]' $xml | select -expand node
```

Then you can loop through those to extract the information that you want by filtering out the "custom orders" (see where command) and putting all the info you need in a new custom powershell object:

```
$automotiveCustomers | foreach{ 
    $customerName = $_.name; 
    $_.Customer | where{$_.name -eq "Customer Orders"} | select -expand Customer | foreach{
        [PSCUstomObject] @{"Customer Name" = $customername; "Order"=$_.value}}}
```

You can modify the command above to use the `-split` operator to split the order on `|` and store in different properties of the custom object. Note that you have to escape the `|` when specifying the split delimiter since its a special character:

```
$automotiveCustomers | foreach{ 
    $customerName = $_.name; 
    $_.Customer | where{$_.name -eq "Customer Orders"} | select -expand Customer | foreach{
        $orderSplit = $_.value -split "\|"; 
        [PSCUstomObject] @{"Customer Name" = $customername; "Status"=$orderSPlit[0]; "Status2"=$orderSplit[1]; "Order"=$orderSplit[2];}}}
```

Comment: That does only select the ones with the Automotive category but, doesnt let me expand the Customer/Customer Orders. Would it be better to put these into a nested ForEach statement?

Comment: @texnoob I have elaborated on my answer.